# Making a container horizontally scrollable?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm creating a container that is `3000px` wide with three subcontainers, each with `flex:1`.

I made the top container horizontally scrollable. However, when I drag to the right, I can see my third box (with word three) but the window snaps back once I release.

I'd like the content on the right to remain visible after I release [Sencha Fiddle](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#Xs8yU/).

[image]

---

Source:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    name: "Sencha",

    launch: function() {

        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
            layout: 'card',
            padding: 2,
            tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

            items: [{
                id: 'tab1',
                title: 'Home',
                layout: 'hbox',
                xtype: 'container',
                width: 3000,
                scrollable: {
                    direction: 'horizontal'
                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    layout: 'vbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    items: [{
                        html: "vb1",
                        flex: 1

                    }, {
                        html: "vb2",
                        flex: 1
                    }]
                }, {
                    html: "two",
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    html: 'three',
                    flex: 1
                }],
                iconCls: 'home'
            }]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(tabPanel);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your fiddle, but w/out writing code I think what you want is a panel with a vbox that contains two panels with layout : ['Card'](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card).

Then you can drop any number of items into the panel and Sencha will do the rest for you.

Please let me know if this doesn't work and I'll try and find time to write you some code.

Good luck, Brad

Comment: It appears SenchaFiddle is broken.  All the code is in my question.  It can simply be copied/pasted into any senchafiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure that I get it.  This can't be right?  "layout : 'Card'.hbox"  I am using a card layout.  I want the entire tab to be horizontally scrollable, with 3 separate panels.

Comment: Could you use a [Carousel](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.carousel.Carousel) inside your hbox?

Comment: Have one now but I don't really like it.